# Connection between frontend server (Node JS and Angular JS) with backend server (.NET API)

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, server, httpurlconnection

I am having an issue with the connection between my frontend server and the backend server. Both solutions are hosted as Web Apps in Azure. The frontend solution is an Angular solution with a Node server, and the backend solution is an API in .NET.

Both solutions are working good without problems, but I want to filter the connections with the API. I mean, I want to set that the IP from the web app in where I hosted the frontend solution is the only IP which is able to connect to the API. But the IP that the API receives is the IP from the client, not from the server in where the web app is hosted, so I need to know what is happening there. I thought that if an user connects to the frontend solution, and the frontend solution calls to an API, the API should receive the IP from the server in where is hosted the frontend solution, not the IP from the client.

I am using Express and this would be the server.js file in Node:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(8080);
```

Something like:

*User (IP: X) -----> Frontend Solution (IP: Y) -----> Backend Solution (IP: Z)*

*Backend Solution should allow the IP Y and deny the IP X.*

Comment: How do you redirect the requests?

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst I do not redirect any request. Should I add some piece of code in the server.js file?

Comment: Maybe the issue is related with the web apps on Azure? Maybe I need to put a proxy in the server file? Does it make sense that the API receives the IP from the client instead of the server? I am a beginner on this side, and I am not sure if I am wrong with some!